# Autoloader not working in a simple PHP file, without being a Class file

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, router, autoload

**Hi,**

I'm using a simple model-view-controller structure and I'm really newbie at this. I'll show you the context:

My `index.php` takes the url `myweb.com/index.php?controller=access&action=login` and requires the `base.php` to show the header and footer.

**index.php:**

```
if ( isset( $_GET['controller']) && isset( $_GET['action'] ) ) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action     = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $controller = 'error';
    $action     = 'notfound';
}

spl_autoload_register();    

require_once('app/base.phtml');
```

The `base.php` puts header and footer html code, and instance a class called `Router` that redirects the request depending on the **controller** and **action** of the url. Note that I'm using`spl_autoload_register();` to autoload my classes.

app/**base.php:**

```
<!-- header code here -->

     use src\model\Router;
     $router = new Router();
     $router->callView($controller, $action);

<!-- footer code here -->
```

src/model/**Router.php:**

```
namespace src\model;

class Router 
{
   function callView($controller, $action)
   {
     // code here that calls a controller to show a view
   }
}
```

The thing is, when I require the `Router` from `base.php`, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class src\model\Router could not be loaded in /var/www/myweb/app/base.php on line 59
```

I thing my paths are correct, maybe I forget something. The autoloader works when I 'use' the 'namespaces' from other classes, but not when I use it from a simple php file.

The structure is the following:

```
myweb
  |- app/
  |   |-- view/
  |   |   |-- login.php
  |   |-- base.php
  |
  |- src/
  |   |-- controller/
  |   |   |-- AccessController.php
  |
  |- model/
  |   |-- Router.php
  |
  |- index.php
  |- .htaccess
```

PD:

- I know I must sanitize the GET requests but this is just the example.
- Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the spl_autoload_register little bit

```
spl_autoload_register(
    function($className) {
        // echo "register: " . $className . "<br>\n";
        $fileName = __DIR__ . '/' .  str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".php";
        // $fileName = __DIR__ . '\\' .  $className . ".php"; // for windows
        if(file_exists($fileName))
        {
            require_once($fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$fileName not found<br>\n";
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You're goddamn right! It works perfect. I added on the top of my index.php.